# Keeping Selected Check Boxes Through Paging in IPagedList<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the best practice method for keeping selected check box values across pagination? I'm using PagedList<> but when I select an item on page one, navigate to page two, and then return to page one, the check box selected will be unchecked.

I don't pass anything to the controller of this nature which will be why, but should this be done with JavaScript or should I be passing the IPagedList back to the controller?

I did try the later but I kept getting an error due to not knowing how I should be passing the model in the paging call to the controller at the bottom of the razor page.

**Edit**
I am trying to pass `Model` within the paramaters of the Paging function, with `IPagedList<VirtualMachine>` as the parameter type in the controller but that gives me the same error.

How can I achieve keeping the check box state across paging so I can send multiple ids back which may or may not be on the page in question?

**Code**

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult VirtualMachines(string sortOrder, string currentSort,
            int? page, int id) // tried passing IPagedList<VirtualMachine>
        {
            try
            {
                int pageSize = 10;
                int pageIndex = 1;
                pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

                IPagedList<VirtualMachine> vmList = null;
                var db = new OnAppDatabase();

                var vms = db.GetHypervisorVMs(id);
                var userIds = new List<string>();
                foreach (var vm in vms)
                {
                    userIds.Add(vm.user_id);
                }
                var usernames = db.GetUsernamesByIds(userIds);

                foreach (var v in vms)
                {
                    var un = usernames.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ContainsKey(v.user_id));
                    v.user = (un == null) ? "Unknown" : un[v.user_id];
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < vms.Count; i++)
                {
                    vms[i] = GetEmailHistory(vms[i]);
                }

                vmList = vms.OrderBy(m => m.user).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);

                currentSort = sortOrder;
                ViewBag.SortOrder = sortOrder;
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = currentSort;
                ViewBag.Label = db.GetHypervisorLabelById(id.ToString());
                return View(vmList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

**Razor** I have tried to strip out all of the bloat which was in the page, beneath you can see the check boxes that are on each page (ten items per page) I am trying to keep the selected check boxes across paging.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hypervisors", "Hypervisors","Notification", null, new { @class = "submit-btn btn btn-yellow reverse-btn" })
                @using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmails", "Notification", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "noForm" }))
                {
                    <table class="general-table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Select
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                VM ID
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Hostname
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                User ID
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                User
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Last Sent
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Sent Type
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Ticket ID
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr style="@style">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="vm_ids" value="@item.id" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="" style="@style">@item.id</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.hostname)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.user_id)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.user)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.emailSentLast)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.emailSentType)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="" style="@style">@item.ticketId</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
<div id='Paging' style="text-align: center">
                    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
                    of @Model.PageCount
                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("VirtualMachines",
                   new
                   {
                       page,
                       sortOrder = ViewBag.sortOrder,
                       Model 
                   }))
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible with the basic behavior of `IPagedList` and it's also probably a bad idea.

The only solution I could think of here is to have an event on the `page` link that will store all the checked element in your `localStorage`/`array` and then when you click on your final submit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, why would it be a bad idea though? Was thinking of using `ViewBag/TempData` to store the array of IDs, then could use javascript or similar to repopulate the selected check boxes when they appear on the page? Else they'll be able to submit ten at a time, which isn't a huge problem, just exploring options.